# Android load video in VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview

I want to load a video in a video view from raw folder with the following code

```
 String uri = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.preview;
 VideoView mVideoView  = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
 mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri));
 mVideoView.requestFocus();
 mVideoView.start();
```

I receive `NullPointerException` at this line: `mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri));`
Any ideas in what should I do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the `findViewById` function call is returning a VideoView object and is not null.

Null pointer errors typically happen when you call an method to a object that is null.

Chances are the reference to `R.id.videoView1`in your layout xml file is wrong or you could have an error in your xml layout file that isn't showing up.

If you're using Eclipse or Android Studio, the `R.i.videoView1` should be blue, showing that it was found in the layout file.

Also you can verify the object isn't null before calling the methods to be sure. See below:

```
 String uri = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.preview;
 VideoView mVideoView  = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
 if (mVideoView != null)
 {  mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri));
    mVideoView.requestFocus();
    mVideoView.start();
 } else
 { //toast or print "mVideoView is null"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.preview;
VideoView mVideoView  = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
```